# I can't use the apt-get -f install

Tags: apt

I want to use install the `python-numpy`. However, I can't install it, so I want to use the `apt-get -f install`. there are another problem. Could you help me? thank you very much!

```
root@hly:~# apt-get install python-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cracklib-runtime : Depends: file
 hplip : Depends: cups (>= 1.1.20)
 indicator-printers : Depends: cups (>= 1.5)
 language-pack-en-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6)
 libfontconfig1-dev : Depends: libexpat1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libfreetype6-dev (>= 2.1.7) but it is not going to be installed
 libfontenc-dev : Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libfuntools1 : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libncurses5-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                            libc-dev
 libpython2.7-dev : Depends: libexpat1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                                libc-dev
 lintian : Depends: file
 printer-driver-gutenprint : Depends: cups (>= 1.3.0)
 printer-driver-hpcups : Depends: cups
                         Depends: cups (>= 1.4.0) or
                                  cupsddk but it is not installable
 printer-driver-splix : Depends: cups (>= 1.5.0-3~)
 python-numpy : Depends: libblas3 but it is not going to be installed or
                         libblas.so.3
                Depends: liblapack3 but it is not going to be installed or
                         liblapack.so.3
 ubuntu-standard : Depends: file
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


root@hly:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdmx-dev libdmx1 libdrm-dev libfs-dev libfs6 libgfortran-5-dev libice-dev
  libmircookie-dev libmircookie2 libmircore-dev libpciaccess-dev
  libpixman-1-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc
  libxau-dev libxaw7-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev
  libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxfont2 libxi-dev
  libxinerama-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbfile-dev libxmu-dev libxmu-headers
  libxmuu-dev libxpm-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev libxres-dev libxss-dev
  libxt-dev libxtst-dev libxv-dev libxvmc-dev libxxf86dga-dev libxxf86vm-dev
  mesa-common-dev x11proto-bigreqs-dev x11proto-composite-dev
  x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dmx-dev x11proto-dri2-dev
  x11proto-dri3-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-fonts-dev x11proto-gl-dev
  x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-present-dev x11proto-randr-dev
  x11proto-record-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-resource-dev
  x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-video-dev x11proto-xcmisc-dev
  x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xf86bigfont-dev x11proto-xf86dga-dev
  x11proto-xf86dri-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon
  cups-server-common file libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libcups2
  libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libexpat1-dev
  libfreetype6-dev libpng12-dev locales zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  cups-pdf smbclient xpp glibc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cups file libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libexpat1-dev libfreetype6-dev
  libpng12-dev locales zlib1g-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon
  cups-server-common libc6 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1
  libcupsppdc1
12 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 349 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 38.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't locate Debconf/Log.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Debconf::Log module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.28.1/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.28.1) at (eval 1) line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 4.
) -- aborting
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: '349 not upgraded' indicates that you have had some of these problems for a long time. Do you recall what you were trying to do that caused these problems?

Comment: thanks for your remind. However, I can't remember the caused. Is there any other way to try it fix it?

Comment: Well, it seems pretty obvious that long ago you installed some king of wrong-version or non-Ubuntu packages that conflict with a lot of your system. Somehow you also broke Perl and your $PATH. To fix the problems, you must uninstall those wrong-version packages, reinstall Perl, and manually fix your $PATH. Since you cannot do all three (you do not recall the packages), consider backing up your data and then doing a clean install.

Comment: OK, thanks. I try to install my computer again.

Comment: I use the Ubuntu 16.04. Just want to install the software.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did not have this kind of problem, but I found some helpful instructions to fix the problem with `perl`:

First of all, make sure if this fixes your problem:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If it does not work, do the following steps:

1) Create a file in some directory:

```
gedit perl-fix.sh
```

2) Copy the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

# change INC to have Ubuntu's deb/apt calls to custom perl use
# old perl's deb perl stuff

custom=$( env -i perl -V |\
sed -n -e '/^ *@INC/,${/usr\/local\/lib\/perl5\/5.*[0-9]$/p}' )

echo Custom perl is in $custom

pushd /usr/share/perl5 > /dev/null
for f in $( echo * )
do ls ${custom}/$f 2>/dev/null ||\
sudo ln -s /usr/share/perl5/$f ${custom}/$f
echo File or dir here\: $f
done

# not sure if we need to also do for /usr/local/lib/perl5/[older perl] stuff

popd > /dev/null
```

3) Save and exit

4) Run:

```
sh perl-fix.sh
```

Feel free to post any comments if something goes wrong.
[Source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/debconf-perl-may-be-unconfigured-can%27t-locate-debconf-log-pm-in-%40inc-849597/)

Comment: Thank, I follow the step which you give me. The results as follow :hly@hly:~$ cd bin/
hly@hly:~/bin$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for hly: 
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin

Comment: hly@hly:~/bin$ gedit perl-fix.sh
hly@hly:~/bin$ sh perl-fix.sh 
Custom perl is in /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.28.1
perl-fix.sh: 11: perl-fix.sh: pushd: not found
File or dir here: colorbar_basics.py
File or dir here: mass.py
File or dir here: periodo2
File or dir here: perl-5.28.2
File or dir here: perl-5.28.2.tar.gz
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.28.1/perl-fix.sh
File or dir here: perl-fix.sh
perl-fix.sh: 20: perl-fix.sh: popd: not found

Comment: I think my computer has a big problem as the first answer said. Broke Perl and my $PATH. Maybe install my computer is best way. Anyway, thanks you!